# JSON - extract call from REST call

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a third party database which has a rest API. When I make a call I get an error back (which I am expecting in my case):

```
transaction.commit(function(err) {
if (err){
   var par = JSON.parse(err); \\ returns error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

   console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
   console.log(err);
   console.log('' + err);

  //First console.log return:  {"code":409,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}}}
  //Second console.log return:  { Error: entity already exists: app: "s~myapp"<br/>path <<br/>  Element {<br/>    type: "v"<br/>    name: "bob@gmail.com"<br/>  }<br/>><br/>
  //Third console.log returns:  Error: entity already exists: app: "s~myapp"<br/>path <<br/>  Element {<br/>    type: "v"<br/>    name: "bob@gmail.com"<br/>  }<br/>><br/>



}
{);
```

I need to extract the error field and the type field. I have tried to parse the JSON and then go par.error or par.type to get the variables, but I can't parse the object because I get an error.
[image]

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a JS object already.

Comment: @zerkms I tried going console.log(err.type); or console.log(err.type); and get undefined for both.

Comment: It is impossible that `console.log(JSON.stringify(err));` and `console.log(err);` return the same results. First run it again and copy the exact output from both (they must be different)

Comment: @zerkms Sorry I have fixed this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently having an `Error` object, that has a `message` property to extract the message string.

Hence use

```
err.message
```

to obtain it.

References:

- [`Error.prototype.message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/message)
- [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: @user2924127 it's not possible. `err.message` must return you the error message. Show the **screenshot** of `console.log(err.toString())` and `console.log(err.valueOf())` in the console

Comment: ... and `console.log(err instanceof Error)`

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the question now: First error is err.toString(), second is err.valueOf() and third is err instanceof Error. Sorry since it is a production sever I have to blank out some information.

Comment: Based on that - it's impossible that `err.message` does not return you the error message.

Comment: I am so sorry, I thought err.message was just a template for err.error. When I type in err.message yes this returns a very similar string, but without the Error label. I need to be able though to extract the error and type fields from this.

Comment: @user2924127 `Error:` prefix is not the part of the error message. But you can get it with it using `err.toString()` as you did 10 minutes ago. At the moment I'm lost and not sure how either `err.message` or `err.toString()` is not what you asked. If you need to *parse* the error message, it would be a different problem. And honestly - if you can change it on the other side you better do, since the current message is not well suited for that. Otherwise - regular expressions is the (dirty) way to do that.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. I need to extract the error field so I would get 'entity already exists' and the type field's value if 'v'. I have no control over the service, it is Google Datastore that returns this so that is what Google returns.

Comment: @user2924127 `err.message.match(/^[^:]+/)[0]` for the initial error message, `err.message.match(/type:\s+"([^"]+)/)[1]` for the type.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH IT WORKS NOW!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your results, it seems that the `err` parameter that you're getting is already an object and not a JSON string, so you don't need to parse it at all.

You should be able to get `err.code` without problem.

You did mention that you need to get the error type -- but that seems to not be available in that object at all (and that's why you'd get `undefined` while you tried it.

However, by using `err.Error` you should be able to get the error string.

If you're unsure of what data the object has, you can try the following:

1. Execute `console.dir(err)` -- this should give you a good understanding of what the `err` object contains.
2. Just debug up to that point and look around in the `err` object.
3. (Best option) Check the platform's / libraries API documentation, it should tell you what error information it returns so you can use exactly that.

Comment: The type does exist in the string doesn't it? The value is type: "v". I try console.log(err.Error) and always get undefined